# If equation of two curves are given and they intesect and ask to find some constant

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=k^3 x + k^3 - 2$ cuts the curve $g(x)=1/2(\ln x^2)$ at exactly one point then '$k$' may lie in the interval.
In this question I compared the two functions.

$k^3x+k^3-2$=$1/2(lnx^2)$

Then i common out '$K^3$' and drew the graph of '$K^3$' and  '$(1/2(lnx^2)+2)/(x+1)$' individually.

And tried to find out the value 'K' which arrive only one time in graph .
But I got the wrong answer.

Comment: Have you tried plotting the graphs to see what they look like? The idea is that both graphs are monotonic (increasing if $k>0$ and decreasing if $k<0$). What would that tell you?

Comment: Is it $\frac 12\ln(x^2)=\ln|x|$ or $\frac 1{2\ln(x^2)}$ ?

Comment: Zwim-- my mean  ln(|x|)

Answer (score 1):

You properly consider the function
$$f(x)=\frac{\log \left(x^2\right)+2}{2 (x+1)}$$ Now, even without graphing it, you have

- $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \, f(x))=- \infty\qquad$ because of the logarithm
- $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \, f(x))=- \infty\qquad$ because of the logarithm

So, since you need only one intersection point, you must have $k^3 >0$.

But, we also have that

- $\lim_{x\to -1^+} \, f(x))=+ \infty\qquad$ because of the denominator
- $\lim_{x\to \infty} \, f(x))=0^+\qquad$ because the denominator varies faster than the numerator

So $k$ must be larger than the maximum value of the function.

The first derivative
$$f'(x)=\frac{2-x \log \left(x^2\right)}{2 x (x+1)^2}$$ cancels when
$x \log(x^2)=2$ which is the same as $x\log(x)=1$ since $x>0$. So, the derivative cancels at
$$x_*=\frac{1}{W(1)}=\frac 1 \Omega$$ ($W(.)$ being Lambert function). At this point
$$f(x_*)=W(1)=\Omega$$

So, ......